# How to change to the center of a marker on a HTML button click

Tags: javascript, c#, html, google-maps-api-3

I'm using google maps API and want to set the center of the map to a specific location when a (html)button is clicked.

I've tried adding a function called newLocation that takes two parameters for the longtitude and latitude. Then a different function is connected to the button with ID "TestButton".

HTML Buttons

```
<button class="item-button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
<button class="item-button" id="TestButton"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
</div>
```

CSS

```
     #map {
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            right: 0;
        }
```

Creating the map and settings

```
 var map;
        function initMap() {

            //Set center map
            var CenterLoc = { lat: 51.34, lng: 5.53 };

            //Set map settings
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
                {
                    center: CenterLoc,
                    disableDefaultUI: true,
                    zoom: 3,
                });
```

creating function and setting center

```
            //Center function
            function newLocation(newLat, newLng) {
                map.setCenter({
                    lat: newLat,
                    lng: newLng
                });
            }

             google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);

            //Setting location center 
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("TestButton").on('click', function () {
                    newLocation(48.1293954, 11.556663);
                });
            });

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

These are all the code parts which I think are relavent for this problem. However the entire code is here: https://pastebin.com/dzFYYtDH

I'm not getting any errors in the browser console. But nothing is happening when I'm pressing the button.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JQuery, to select or to find a unique HTML element using it's id attribute, you will need to use the **`#id`** Selector.

In your case, use the following:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
   $("#TestButton").on('click', function () {
     newLocation(48.1293954, 11.556663);
   });
 });
```

Here's a working sample in **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3vmgn0b4/)**.
More info on JQuery #id Selector **[here](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)**.

Hope this helps!